# Using setTimeout to Add and remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I want to add and remove a class to a div on the basis of time. It should add a class after 6 secs and remove it after 4 secs. I tried a basic implementation. why isn't [this](https://jsfiddle.net/iamanoopchandran/js6wh78h/3/) working? I assume the problem is two setTimeouts together like this. If I comment out the second line the first one works. What is happening here?

```
setTimeout(addHighlight(), 6000);
setTimeout(removeHighlight(), 10000);
```

Can somebody show me how i can write a single function that does both(add and remove class) on the basis of a `delay` parameter?

Comment: Try `setTimeout(function() { addHighlight(); setTimeout(function() { removeHighlight() }, 4000) }, 6000);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#square').addClass('highlight');
}, 6000);

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#square').removeClass('highlight');
}, 10000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/js6wh78h/8/

Comment: Why doesn't my code work? It is basically the same. I have defined `function(){
    $('#square').addClass('highlight');
  }` as `addHighlight` and called like this` setTimeout(addHighlight(), 6000);`

Comment: Replace your  setTimeout(addHighlight(), 6000); to  setTimeout(addHighlight, 6000); In both setTimeout function

Comment: I see what I've done, Thank you for pointing that out. it was a deal-breaker.

Answer (score -2):

This is probably what you want to do:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  $("#test").addClass('on');
  
  setTimeout(function(){
     $("#test").removeClass('on');
  }, 4000);
}, 6000);
```

```css
.on {
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">hello world</div>
```

The first timeout executes after 6 seconds, adds a class to the div and starts another timeout, wich executes after 4 seconds and removes the class.

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted? This answer tried to club both functionalities together in one as I required.

Comment: @anoopchandran probably because the first version wasn't using jquery. I added it afterwards.